# How can I use Selenium to click multiple plus buttons and show their entire content

Tags: python-3.x, selenium

I want to click and open multiple plus buttons and print out their texts. Here is the code that I have:

```
from selenium import webdriver
chrome_path=r"G:\My Drive\chrome_driver\chromedriver_win32\chromedriver.exe"
driver=webdriver.Chrome(chrome_path)
driver.get('https://meshb.nlm.nih.gov/treeView')
for links in driver.find_elements_by_css_selector('a.ng-scope'):
    links.find_element_by_xpath("following-sibling::span").click();
    for sublinks in links.find_elements_by_xpath("//*[@class='ng-scope']/span"):
        print(sublinks.text)
```

here is what I see! the nodes' text is duplicated! and the code cannot open all the plus buttons. Only the first level plus buttons are opened, how can I change my code to be able to open all plus buttons, and once every plus button is open, I see the node'stext along with the whole content that is associated with it?
A part of html looks like this:

```
<a class="ng-scope">
   <span class="ng-binding ng-scope">Anatomy [A]</span>
</a>
    <ul class="treeItem ng-scope">
        <li class ="ng-scope" >
              < a  class ="ng-scope" href="/record/ui?ui=D001829" >
              < span  class ="ng-binding ng-scope" > Body Regions[A01] < / span >
              </a>
        </li>
        < li class ="ng-scope" >
              <a  class ="ng-scope" href="/record/ui?ui=D001829" >
                < span  class ="ng-binding ng-scope" > Cardio Vascular< / span >
              </a>
                    <ul class="treeItem ng-scope">
                        <li class="ng-scope">
                           <a class="ng-scope" href="/record/ui?ui=D015824">
                           <span class="ng-binding ng-scope">Blood-Air Barrier [A07.025]</span>
                           </a>
                                 <ul class="treeItem ng-scope">                    
                                   <li class="ng-scope">
                                       <a class="ng-scope" href="/record/ui?ui=D018916">
                                       <span class="ng-binding ng-scope">Blood-Aqueous Barrier [A07.030]</span>                        
                                       </a>
                                    </li>
                                 </ul>
                        </li>
                    </ul>
        </li>
    </ul>
```

[image]

Comment: It looks like the application you are testing is using Angular. I don't think Selenium is that good with Angular web applications. Have you looked into Protractor? Try to create first loop to click first level of links, and than second loop will click the second level items.

Comment: Would be nice to see html that you are working with.

Comment: @sen4ik posted! Thx